# I want to call another function after onsubmit performed in form

Tags: javascript, html

Please give me some suggestions, I was trying to run following code :

```
< form name="form1" action="some_action" method="post" onsubmit="somefunction(); return false;">

.... some code...

< input type="submit" value="GET">

< /form>
```

Here, I want to run onsubmit (which is running well and as expected giving some dialog box as output, working fine)

Then I want to run action which is not running (because of return false in onsubmit) but I want to run it as well by any way.

```
< form action="login/buy_artifact/0/<?=$row['A_ID']?>/<?=$userid?>" onSubmit="return btn(<?=$i?>,<?=$row['A_ID']?>,<?=$userid?>);">

< input type="submit" name="submit" value=" GET ">
< /form>

function btn(id,art_id,user_id)
    {   
    //alert("called"+id);
      var id=id;
      var name = document.getElementById("name"+id).innerHTML; 
      var desc = document.getElementById("description"+id).innerHTML;
      var credit = document.getElementById("creditsforquestion"+id).innerHTML;

      var art_id=art_id;
      var user_id=user_id;

      // Only send param data for sample. These parameters should be set
      // in the callback.
      var order_info = { "name":name,
                         "description":desc,
                         "credit":credit,
                         "aid":art_id,
                         "uid":user_id
                       };

      // calling the API ...
      var obj = {
        method: 'pay',
        order_info: order_info,
        purchase_type: 'item'
      };

      FB.ui(obj, callback);     
    var callback = function(data) {

      if (data['order_id']) {

        writeback("Transaction Completed! </br></br>"
        + "Data returned from Facebook: </br>"
        + "<b>Order ID: </b>" + data['order_id'] + "</br>"
        + "<b>Status: </b>" + data['status']);

      } else if (data['error_code']) {

        writeback("Transaction Failed! </br></br>"
        + "Error message returned from Facebook:</br>"
        + data['error_message']);
        return false;
      } else {

        writeback("Transaction failed!");
      }

    };

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<form name="form1" action="some_action" method="post" onsubmit="return somefunction();">
    .... some code...
    <input type="submit" value="GET" />
</form>
```

and then in your `somefunction` decide whether to return true or false based on some condition:

```
function somefunction() {
    if (....) {
        // do something and return true in order to submit the form
        return true;
    } else {
        // do not submit the form
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey Darin,you are near to close, using this function it is not working properly but,

function somefunction() {
    if (....) {
        // do something and return true in order to submit the form
        return FALSE; / *  using this it will work */
    } else {
        // do not submit the form
        return false;
    }
}
NEED TO SOME MODIFICATION BECAUS, after returning false action will work

Comment: PLEASE try to give other solution for this or try to make this workable

Comment: Amit, if you have errors in your script, the form will submit regardless. Look in the console for errors

Comment: mplungjan, No it is not giving me any error just it is not performing action of that form(that i want to run)

Comment: @Amit, you have to `return true` from the function if you want the form to be submitted.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, yes but if function return true then dialogue box which display after clicking submit button will not show only action will perform so, I appreciate this.

Comment: @Amit, what dialog box are you talking about? Maybe if you provided a little more details about what you are trying to achieve and show your code we will be able to help you.

Comment: @Amit, inside the callback you could manually submit the form: `document.getElementById('someIdOfTheForm').submit();`. And from the `btn` callback always `return false`.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Great appreciated answer. Thnks for quick response. I used same but little bit different way like this.it works.

Answer (score 0):

remove return false; from onsubmit

Comment: if i removed return false;  then  some_function will not show output(which are dialogue boxes)

Comment: PLease try to give some other suggestions PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

In form tag use

```
onsubmit="return somefunction();"
```

And in javascript function return false if any condition didn't met , otherwise in methods last return true;